# Secondary read preference

Tags: digital-ocean, mongodump

I am trying to do mongodump in Digital Ocean ubuntu server.I am getting following error.

```
root@Project:~# sudo mongodump --db <database>  --out  /root/backup/Localdb

2018-11-07T06:28:09.177+0000    Failed: error getting collections for database `<database>`: error running `listCollections`. Database: `<database>` Err: not authorized on `<database>` to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: {}, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: `<database>` }
```

How to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if you edited the shell output above. If not, '<database>' should be the name of your database.

Comment: Yes, i have edited the shell output. My database name is there at <database>. i dont want to display my database name. So i have mentioned my database as a syntax.